# MongoDb Access array of objects with certain property

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have one document as follows:

```
{
    user: 'hvt07',
    photos: [
    {
        link: 'http://link.to.com/image1.jpg',
        isPrivate: true
    },
    {
        link: 'http://link.to.com/image2.jpg',
        isPrivate: false
    }
    ]
}
```

I want to get all photos which are with:

```
isPrivate: false
```

I am using the following query:

```
db.collection_name.find({ photos:{ $elemMatch:{isPrivate: false} } }).pretty()
```

I have also tried:

```
db.collection_name.find({'photos.isPrivate': true}).pretty()
```

But both return all elements in the array even ones that are set as :

```
isPrivate: true
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) is the solution.

You need to deconstruct the `photos` array using the  [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) operator. Next use the [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) to select documents where `isPrivate: false`. The [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) you can regroup your documents by `_id` and reconstruct your `photos` array using the [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push) operator

```
db.collection_name.aggregate(
     [
       {$unwind: "$photos"}, 
       {$match: {"photos.isPrivate": false}}, 
       {$group: {"_id": {"id": "$_id", "user": "$user"}, photos: {$push: "$photos"}}}
       {$project: {"_id": "$_id.id", "user": "$_id.user", "photos": 1, "_id": 0 }}
     ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $elemMatch to the result projection like this

```
db.collection_name.find(
{ photos:{ $elemMatch:{isPrivate: false} } },   //1

{photos:{$elemMatch:{isPrivate: false}}})  //2
```

1. Find all documents that have at least a photo which is not private
2. Select only photos that are not private for the documents found.

Comment: This returns only the first record and not all records with "{isPrivate: false}"